# Download stops at 99% and gives error

Tags: google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer, download, webserver

Some EXEs from our website are not downloading completely. (ex: "winmansoftware.com/files/WinmanCAERP_Update.EXE")

Download completes 99% and gives error.  But the same EXEs are downloading from other websites like Drop Box etc. Error message is shown here [image]

Error is coming in less than 1% of our customers’ Pcs. For remaining customers same files get downloaded properly. EXE is digitally signed with thawte code signing certificate. Certification path is as shown here [image]

We tried various options as mentioned below. (but in all the cases problem persisted)

1. Tried with different browsers - chrome, Firefox.
2. Cleared DNS configurations and IP reset
3. Uninstalled Client pc Antivirus
4. Disabled our web server antivirus.
5. Error comes in our own download utility (using winsock) also.
6. We restarted our web server.

When we compressed our exe (as .zip) file got downloaded & got extracted. Our
We are using “Windows Server 2008 R2” in our web server. We have 2 web servers and both are of same configuration.

#### Server Configuration:

OS: Windows Server 2008 R2

Antivirus: Symantec  Endpoint Protection 2012

#### Client PC Configuration:

Operating System Version - Windows XP Service Pack 3

Antivirus: Avast in one PC & Kaspersky Internet security 2013 in other PCs

Internet connection: Wired Broad Band with automatic IP configuration

Internet Explorer Version - Internet Explorer 6.0.2900

In Summary

1. Same file can be downloaded from Dropbox
2. If we compress it gets downloaded from our website with no issues,
3. Lots of other computers still can download .exe itself without error (more than 2500 PCs have downloaded it & error comes in around 5 PCs)

If it was web server issue then other customers could not have downloaded. If it was customer PC issue they could not have downloaded it from Dropbox. Now how to trace error? What are the solutions?

Comment: Does this occur with specific *machines* or specific *connections*? In other words, what happens if you take a machine exhibiting this issue and try it on a known good connection? Or take a known good machine and try it on the potentially problematic connection?

Comment: No.There is no problem in other PCs connected to same LAN.

Comment: After a file is downloaded, it is usually appended into one part. Probably an error in that part?

Comment: No. download managers will download file as in part. But I think IE and Chromes are downloades files directly. We didnt used download managers to download EXEs

Comment: I dont' know the answer, but Internet Explorer Version - Internet Explorer 6.0.2900 rings alarm bells for me. This browser is really ancient and should be updated.

Comment: @WayneJohnston: True (IE6 *deserves* to die a horrible death), but he did say different browsers have been tried.

Comment: @winman: The fact that compressed files were downloaded fine on the same PCs does suggest an issue with EXEs. I see you've already tried with AVs disabled. If those PCs are able to download EXEs from other sites just fine it becomes difficult to know which end to assign blame to, since you are able to serve the same files properly to most other users. This is a real head scratcher...

Comment: Ya, but we are tried with different browsers. also no problem for more than 2000 customers with same EXs.

Comment: Today i have done another test. I have tried to download the same exe file with no digital sign(I am using digital sign from thawte). The file downloaded properly!! As i said before the file downloaded  with digital sign for more than 2500 customers.So what may be reason for the download error??

Comment: Only additional test that I can think of is to use Process Monitor and see what processes are accesing the downloading temp file, or the final downloaded file

Comment: IE6 is a vulnerability paradise. please consider upgrading it or using another major browser which have added security and stability

Comment: What happens if you download the file directly using a simple tool such as curl or wget?